# Set state in handleChange

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to set the state to the current select item in the dropdown. I thought there would be an easier way of doing this than going through the whole, action/reducer chain. But in this case `setState` will always be empty and `componentWillReceiveProps` will never be called.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("collection next props", nextProps);
    this.setState({
      currentList: nextProps.currentList,
    });
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    console.log('handle change called', e.target.value); //Value is received
    //this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    this.setState({currentList: e.target.value}); //This is never getting the value
    this.props.fetchlistOfAssets(e.target.value); //This action executes without problem

  };

  render() {
    /* Read from market and last price */
    const postItems = this.props.indexes.map(post => (

      <option key={post} value={post}>{post}</option>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Select index</h1>
        <select name="index" onChange={this.handleChange}>{postItems}</select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit adding connect and mapState

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  indexes: state.posts.indexdays,
  currentList: state.posts.currentList
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchIndexDays, fetchlistOfAssets }
)(CollectionDropDown);
```

Comment: How do you check that setState is never getting the value

Comment: redux dev tools. Also the console.log is never fired for componentWill....

Comment: well componentWillReceiveProps will never fire because of state update. Although fetchlistOfAssets will fire it its the props updated in the reducer and the component is connected correctly. Can you should your connect functions mapStatetoProps and mapDispatchToProps and make sure that you are using the connected component

Comment: OP `state` in `mapStateToProps` refers to the state data of Redux's store, while `this.setState` is for updating local state of component. They are not related.

Comment: Yes I can't seem to find a way around setting this the "normal" way through action/reducer